# I am not able to align vertical touch event owl carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins

Please find the below link and find the solution if possible to make owl carousel vertical."jsfiddle.net/nLJ79/"

Comment: i just want vertical touch carousal

Answer (score 0):

Owl Carouse With Vertical Animation

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  autoplay: true,
  items: 1,
  nav: true,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  animateOut: 'slideOutUp',
  animateIn: 'slideInUp'
});
```

Above code work like vertical slide animate.

you have apply ***slideOutUp*** and ***slideInUp*** Animate css.

Comment: it is not making it vertical... :(